# ¿Como hacer una consulta mysql para grafico php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Necesito hacer una consulta en MYSQL, tengo la siguiente data

```
COLUM1  FECHA   PAIS
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Reino Unido
0   2018-11-13  
1   2018-11-13  Colombia
0   2018-11-13  
1   2018-11-13  Peru
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Espana
1   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Colombia
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  USA
0   2018-11-13  
1   2018-11-13  Brasil
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Uruguay
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Peru
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Costa Rica
0   2018-11-13  Costa Rica
0   2018-11-13  
1   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  USA
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Peru
1   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  USA
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  USA
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  USA
1   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  USA
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Costa Rica
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Argentina
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Argentina
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Paraguay
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Peru
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Colombia
1   2018-11-13  
1   2018-11-13  
1   2018-11-13  Argentina
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Peru
0   2018-11-13  
0   2018-11-13  Colombia
```

En la columna `COLUM1` se puede notar `0` y `1` en donde el `0` representa `EXITOSO` y `1` `NO EXITOSO`

Lo que necesito traerme es lo siguiente:

- **El total de `EXITOSO` para cada pais**
- **El total de `NO EXITOSO` para cada pais**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se pueden obtener los totales en diferentes queries:

> El total de paises

```
select count(*) as cant from (select distinct pais from <tu tabla>) as p;
```

> El total de EXITOSO para cada pais

```
select count(*) as cant, pais from <tu tabla> where column1 = 0 group by pais;
```

> El total de NO EXITOSO para cada pais

```
select count(*) as cant, pais from <tu tabla> where column1 = 1 group by pais;
```

> Y se puede hacer solamente sacando el no exitoso y exitoso por pais ?

Para poner la cantidad de exitosos y no exitosos en la misma fila hay que hacer un `JOIN` entre los dos subqueries. 
Si todos los países aparecen en los dos subqueries se puede hacer un join entre las dos tablas sin pérdida de datos. Pero haciendo esto si algún país aparece solo en uno de los dos subqueries, ese país no saldrá en el resultado final.

Para tener todos los resultados, ya sea que el país este de un lado, del otro, o en los dos, tendríamos que usar un `FULL JOIN`. Pero Mysql no tiene FULL JOIN.
En un artículo encontré que se puede simular con los `LEFT` y `RIGHT JOIN` que están abajo.

```
select COALESCE(exitoso.paise, noexitoso.paisne) Pais, cante, cantne
from (
    select *
    from (select count(*) as cante, pais paise from <tu tabla> where column1 = 0 group by pais) as exitoso
    left join
         (select count(*) as cantne, pais paisne from <tu tabla> where column1 = 1 group by pais) as noexitoso
    on (exitoso.paise = noexitoso.paisne)
    union all
    select * 
    from (select count(*) as cante, pais paise from <tu tabla> where column1 = 0 group by pais) as exitoso
    right join
         (select count(*) as cantne, pais paisne from <tu tabla> where column1 = 1 group by pais) as noexitoso
    on (exitoso.paise = noexitoso.paisne)
    where exitoso.paise is null
) as exitopais
order by COALESCE(exitoso.paise, noexitoso.paisne)
```

Comment: Necesito hace todo eso en la misma consulta

Comment: Se te va a repetir el total de países en todas las filas no importa?

Comment: Como asi ? no entiendo

Comment: Si metes todo en una sola consulta tenes como resultado Pais | cant existoso | cant no exitoso | cant de países. cant de países tiene el mismo valor independientemente del país de la fila.

Comment: Y se puede hacer solamente sacando el no exitoso y exitoso por pais ?

Comment: El query que agregué debe funcionar. Fijate de cambiar el nombre de <tu tabla>